# Stripe.js token was not passed! (using Webform Integration)

Tags: webform-civicrm, stripe

I am on Drupal 7.51 / Civi 4.7.12 / Stripe Extension 4.7.1

I use a Webform to register a membership, and I have integrated a Contribution Page based upon a Stripe Payment Processor (with "Live Transactions" mode).

I get the following message :
*A fatal error was triggered: Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this message to the site administrator.*

I see on the Stack Exchange that this already happened in the past, but not clear it was with Webforms.

I also know that not all payment processors are compatible with webforms : is it the case with stripe ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a long thread at https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/76 on this issue.  It was for earlier versions but might give you some clues.   I have a site using Stripe successfully with webforms on Civi 4.6

Comment: Thank you Aidan for your quick answer : I read this thread, which drives to https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/159/files (make civicrm_sripe js load in webform), which gives a patch for stripe.php, but I don't find any sripe.php file which looks like this one (FYI, I have installed the default Stripe extension (4.7.1) via Admin>SystemSettings>Extensions>Add). Could you tell me a little more, because I feel a bit confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I could finally fix my problem, following Aidan's suggestion : modify /civi_extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/stripe.php as per https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/159/files (to "Make civicrm_stripe js load in webform")

... and it worked

Thanks a lot Aidan (forget my comment)