# URGENT : Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this message to the site administrator. (on civicrm 4.7.20)

Tags: stripe

I recently upgraded civicrm from 4.7.16 to 4.7.20 (on Drupal 7.56).

Now, when I use a Contribtion Page to make a payment, I get the following message : "Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this message to the site administrator." (tested on different existing Contribution Pages with same result).

I already had this same message in the past, for webform embedded payments (see [Stripe.js token was not passed! (using Webform Integration)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/stripe-js-token-was-not-passed-using-webform-integration)), but it was solved by a fix (https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/159/files).

But this time, the problem happens on simple Contribution Pages (which previously worked).

To be complete, since this upgrade, I have had an other problem on webform embedded payments (submitted here : [Stripe extension fails with a new account (civi 4.7.20)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19293/stripe-extension-fails-with-a-new-account-civi-4-7-20)) :

- old webforms continue to work properly (I don't have this stripe.js
  message and the payments succeed) (but for how long ?)
- new webforms based upon new stripe Accounts send the payment to an other (existing) account.

May be both problems are linked ?

FYI, I use Stripe Extension 4.7.1 and I am not a programmer

Too late for me to go back to 4.7.16, any help is very very welcome and urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to the current github 4.7-dev version. Lots of work went into eliminating "Stripe.js token not passed!" errors that can for **a variety** of reasons. Jacques-Marie, you can reap the benefits of this labor by upgrading.

You already posted the url, but this is it:

https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe

Comment: can you clarify why by eg pointing to the fix? oh do you mean stripe 4.7-dev maybe? and/or provide the link. currently this answer is flagged as 'low quality'

Comment: I have just upgraded to 4.7.dev, and everything works OK now ; Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Matt Wire has a fork for CiviCRM 5.x here: https://github.com/mattwire/com.drastikbydesign.stripe